# Как получить состояние сетевого принтера и его актуальную очередь заданий

Tags: java, windows, печать, принтер

На локальной машине стоит Windows и подключен сетевой принтер. В принтере нет бумаги. Если я отправлю задание на печать на этот принтер, то в очереди печати на моей локальной машине все выглядит так, будто задание корректно напечаталось на принтере. Т.е. задание появляется в спуллере и исчезает спустя пару секунд. На принтере, соответственно, ничего не печатается. Если вставим бумагу то задание распечатается корректно.

Вопрос: как мне получить статус принтера и состав его очереди печати с моей запущенной таской в момент, когда в принтере нет бумаги? Мне необходимо программно мониторить состояние сетевого принтера и состояние отправленной мною таски на печать и оперативно сообщать о подобных ошибках. Принтера могут быть разные и нельзя закладываться на конкретный драйвер

Ищу решение для java, но целом это не принципиально

Comment: Сетевые принтеры как правило умеют SNMP протокол - поэтому логично смотреть в эту сторону. Разница конечно может быть в параметрах snmp oid-ов, но это как конкретный вендор уже придумал.